# I want to connect to azure databricks and create workspace and do the deployment using powershell commands or rest api. is it possible?

Tags: powershell, rest, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-powershell

I want to connect to databricks and create workspace and do the deployment using powershell commands or rest api. is it possible can you please share the links where i can find some help in order to do this task.

Comment: Stack Overflow is normally used for helping people with coding issues.  Requesting that other users use google what you are looking for is not what this this sight is for.  When you have some code that may not work as you expect, post that with your question.  You will most likely not receive any other feedback than mine.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to connect to databricks and create workspace and do the deployment using powershell commands or rest api.

You first need to install the module from PowerShell Gallery using this Install-Module command.

```
Install-Module azure.databricks.cicd.tools -Scope CurrentUser
Import-Module azure.databricks.cicd.tools
```

For connecting to your workspace, You need an API Bearer token. You can create this in the workspace by clicking on the user icon in the top right corner and selecting User Settings > Generate New Token.

```
Connect-Databricks -Region <String> -ApplicationId <String> -Secret <String> -TenantId <String>
 -SubscriptionId <String> -ResourceGroupName <String> -WorkspaceName <String> [-Force] [<CommonParameters>]
```

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Home · DataThirstLtd/azure.databricks.cicd.tools](https://github.com/DataThirstLtd/azure.databricks.cicd.tools/wiki)
2. [Tools for Deploying Databricks Solutions in Azure](https://github.com/DataThirstLtd/azure.databricks.cicd.tools)